# Semantic-UI container gets margins automatically at certain breakpoints

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic-UI with React JS.

This is my top-most html:

```
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="render-target" class="ui fluid container"></div>
</body>
```

As you can see I am using a fluid ui container, which means I want the container to be as wide as the browser....
This works at a bigger browser size.
However, for some reason, if I reduce the size of the browser, at a certain breakpoint the container gets some margin on both sides automatically.

What is the reason for this and how do I fix this so that it always is as wide as the browser?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this perhaps related? [ui fluid container - view on mobile devices](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2895)

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui.fluid.container {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;

}
```

This made it work for me....